# Part of UWP page doesn't refresh after navigation

Tags: c#, uwp

I've developed an UWP app. There I have a part of the page with charts on the bottom (from Telerik) which sometimes changes the data an then have to be updated. This part of the page is separated from the top of the page by an GridSplitter.

By the way this page is the MainPage.

When I load the page the first time everything works well. Also updating the chart is working.

But if I navigate to another page and then navigate back to the MainPage the loading of the charts doesn't work. Also refreshing the charts with the data doesn't work.

I've tried to use charts from another library (not Telerik) - doesn't work.

I've build my own chart control - doesn't work.

Updating the controls by calling `.UpdateLyout()` also doesn't work.

The top of this part of the page does work (it's a GridView). But it seems that the part of the page which is fully or partly not completely shown on the top of this part the page (because I'm using an ScrollViewer) doesn't refresh. But in the code behind I can see that the data (also in the control) is loaded.

I've also completely deleted the not working UserControl from the containing StackPanel and then added another simple UserControl. But it doesn't refresh. Also I'm sure that I've deleted the chart from the StackPanel it will still be displayed and the new UserControl will not be displayed.

```
        <Grid Name="grd_all_content">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition MinHeight="100" />
                <RowDefinition Height="11" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ucs:SprintListUC x:Name="sprintListUC" Grid.Row="0" />
            <controls:GridSplitter Foreground="White" Grid.Row="1" ResizeBehavior="BasedOnAlignment" ResizeDirection="Auto" Background="Gray" Height="11" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="13">
                <controls:GridSplitter.Element>
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"  IsHitTestVisible="False"
                VerticalAlignment="Center" Text=""
                Foreground="Black" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"/>
                    </Grid>
                </controls:GridSplitter.Element>
            </controls:GridSplitter>
            <Grid Name="grd_graphics" Grid.Row="2" Background="{ThemeResource SystemAltMediumColor}" Padding="10,10,10,20" SizeChanged="Grid_SizeChanged"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrlvwr_charts">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock Foreground="#FFC31727" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20" Margin="0,0,0,20">Auswertung zu der aktuellen Sprint-Auswahl:</TextBlock>
                        <GridView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Path=Evaluations}" SelectionMode="None">
                            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate x:DataType="classes:Evaluation">
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Padding="5" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1" Width="250" Background="#FFC31727">
                                        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" Text="{x:Bind Path=Name}" />
                                        <TextBlock Margin="10,5,0,0" Foreground="White" Text="{x:Bind Path=Value}" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
                        </GridView>


                            <TextBlock Foreground="#FFC31727" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20" Margin="0,20,0,20">Sprints je KW (Gesamt und davon Erledigt):</TextBlock>
                            <telerik:RadCartesianChart PaletteName="DefaultLight" Height="250">
                                <telerik:RadCartesianChart.HorizontalAxis>
                                    <telerik:CategoricalAxis/>
                                </telerik:RadCartesianChart.HorizontalAxis>
                                <telerik:RadCartesianChart.VerticalAxis>
                                    <telerik:LinearAxis/>
                                </telerik:RadCartesianChart.VerticalAxis>
                                <telerik:RadCartesianChart.Grid>
                                    <telerik:CartesianChartGrid MajorLinesVisibility="Y" StripLinesVisibility="Y"/>
                                </telerik:RadCartesianChart.Grid>
                                <telerik:BarSeries ItemsSource="{x:Bind SprintsDoneAmountData}">
                                    <telerik:BarSeries.ValueBinding>
                                        <telerik:PropertyNameDataPointBinding PropertyName="Value"/>
                                    </telerik:BarSeries.ValueBinding>
                                    <telerik:BarSeries.CategoryBinding>
                                        <telerik:PropertyNameDataPointBinding PropertyName="Name"/>
                                    </telerik:BarSeries.CategoryBinding>
                                </telerik:BarSeries>
                                <telerik:BarSeries ItemsSource="{x:Bind SprintsAmountData}" CombineMode="Cluster">
                                    <telerik:BarSeries.ValueBinding>
                                        <telerik:PropertyNameDataPointBinding PropertyName="Value"/>
                                    </telerik:BarSeries.ValueBinding>
                                    <telerik:BarSeries.CategoryBinding>
                                        <telerik:PropertyNameDataPointBinding PropertyName="Name"/>
                                    </telerik:BarSeries.CategoryBinding>
                                </telerik:BarSeries>
                            </telerik:RadCartesianChart>

                            <TextBlock FontSize="16" FontStyle="Italic" Margin="5,5,0,0">(gelb = gesamt; blau = erledigt)</TextBlock>



                            <TextBlock Foreground="#FFC31727" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20" Margin="0,20,0,20">Einsparpotential je KW (in €):</TextBlock>
                            <telerik:RadCartesianChart PaletteName="DefaultLight" Height="250">
                                <telerik:RadCartesianChart.HorizontalAxis>
                                    <telerik:CategoricalAxis/>
                                </telerik:RadCartesianChart.HorizontalAxis>
                                <telerik:RadCartesianChart.VerticalAxis>
                                    <telerik:LinearAxis/>
                                </telerik:RadCartesianChart.VerticalAxis>
                                <telerik:RadCartesianChart.Grid>
                                    <telerik:CartesianChartGrid MajorLinesVisibility="Y" StripLinesVisibility="Y"/>
                                </telerik:RadCartesianChart.Grid>
                                <telerik:BarSeries ItemsSource="{x:Bind SavingPotensialsData}">
                                    <telerik:BarSeries.ValueBinding>
                                        <telerik:PropertyNameDataPointBinding PropertyName="Value"/>
                                    </telerik:BarSeries.ValueBinding>
                                    <telerik:BarSeries.CategoryBinding>
                                        <telerik:PropertyNameDataPointBinding PropertyName="Name"/>
                                    </telerik:BarSeries.CategoryBinding>
                                </telerik:BarSeries>
                            </telerik:RadCartesianChart>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Grid>
```

The GridView ist updating. But the rest of the content of the StackPanel not. Also if I use another simple UserControl and not the Telerik Control.

That's a really tricky problem.

Comment: Don't forget to set `NavigationCacheMode` to cache the page when navigating to other page. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.navigationcachemode

Comment: About refreshing, you need to set the mode of the x:bind to **OneWay** which means once the data updates,the UI will also update. And the default mode is OneTime, it will be only refreshed once. For more details, you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.bindingmode).

Comment: @Littledoe: That was very helpfully! I've set the NavigationCacheMode to "Enabled" and now it works. But navigating to my MainPage ist now very slow (about 3 seconds). Do you have an idea how to make it faster?

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT: That couldn't be the solution, because if I don't use data binding and write the data directly into the UserControl it also doesn't refresh the UI.

Comment: Maybe the `GridView` inside of a `ScrollViewer` is screwing things up.  `GridView` already has internal `Scrollviewer`s.  Also, putting `GridView` inside the `StackPanel` is weird to me, too.  `StackPanel` wants to expand to fit its contents, even off-screen.  `GridView` needs a fixed height/width to properly use virtualization etc.  I'm wondering if there's a layout issue causing your problem.